# Code First update fields without required field

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

this is my entity:

```
public partial class Student
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public int Year { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Config:

```
HasKey(e => new { e.Code, e.Year});

Property(b => b.Code).HasColumnName("CODE").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
Property(b => b.Year).HasColumnName("YEAR").IsRequired();
Property(b => b.Name).HasColumnName("NAME").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(50);
Property(b => b.Gender).HasColumnName("GENDER").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(2).IsRequired();
```

The gender field also has the required option.
In my update I only want to update the name field:

```
var student = new Student
{
   Code = "WRK",
   Year = 2018,
   Name = "Test Name"
};

_context.Student.Attach(student);

_context.Entry(student).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

On SaveChanges it gives a DbEntityValidationException, saying the gender field is required. Although I don't want to update it, but keep the existing value from the database.

Is there a proper solution without first querying the database to get the existing value for that gender field?

Thanks.

Comment: You never query the database, you create a new `Student` that has the `Gender` field not set. There is no "existing value" for it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that is what I do in my code. I create a new Student with fields Code, Year and Name. No Gender. But on SaveChanges it gives the DbEntityValidationException

Comment: If you want to update existed student without loading it, you have to also specify PK, i.e. Id.

Comment: Like Slava says, you need to specify a PK. How is EF supposed to know what Student from the DB you mean otherwise?

Comment: PK is code and year: HasKey(e => new { e.Code, e.Year});

Answer (score 0):

I use solution like this:

```
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer
    For Each changedEntity In Me.ChangeTracker.Entries
        Select Case changedEntity.State
            Case EntityState.Modified
                Select Case If(changedEntity.Entity.GetType.Namespace = "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies", changedEntity.Entity.GetType.BaseType, changedEntity.Entity.GetType)
                    Case GetType(Student)
                        changedEntity.Property("Gender").IsModified = False
        End Select
    Next
    Return MyBase.SaveChanges()
End Function
```